Visite à and Visite de [lieu]. What is the difference?
I want to say that there's a visit to a museum and I don't know which preposition should accompany the verb "visiter". I don't understand the meaning of both ways "visiter à" and "visiter de"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In visit to a museum, visit is a noun, not a verb.

Please provide an example illustrating the problem. You might want to mean "We plan a visit to the museum tomorrow", tentatively offer "Nous prévoyons une visite au musée demain" and explain what's the trouble with this. Or whatever the problem is; your call, actually.

The verb visiter is probably not going to be followed by de or à. The noun visite could. In fact the verb visiter would take a direct object (COD): visiter Versailles, for example.
But you could also say visite de Versailles, if for example it's part of a list of multiple visits to different places: visite de Versailles, visite de Chambord, ...
Visite à Versailles is possible, but a little vague - it sounds as if you are going to visit something that is in Versailles, rather than Versailles itself, but it doesn't make clear what you are going to visit in Versailles.
Je vais rendre visite à quelqu'un à Versailles would be correct, for example, if you want to use à.

Err... visiter quelqu'un does not sound very idiomatic. I personaly use rendre visite à quelqu'un et visiter un lieu ou un monument. Visiter quelqu'un make me think about visiting the internal cavities of the body ;-)

@SergeBallesta OK, tu as raison, j'ai changé.
